Is the geometric mean of two numbers unique?
From my textbook:

Prove that if $a, b$ and $c$ are three successive terms of a geometric sequence, then $b^2=ac$ $(b$ is called geometric mean of $a$ and $c).$

Is this exercise incorrect? I think that the definition in it is vague. It says that the geometric mean $b$ of two numbers $a$ and $c$ is defined by $b^2 = ac.$ But is the geometric mean of two numbers always positive, or it can be negative?
If $a$ and $c$ are positive, then $b$ is positive.
But if $a$ and $c$ are negative, then then $b$ can be both positive and negative. For example, the geometric average of $-1$ and $-4$ can be $-2$ and $2,$ right?

The geometric mean is defined for positive real numbers

thank you a million! Is this problem  true or it has a mistake: if x and x+2 and x+3 are three terms of a geometric sequence, find the value of x, and solution is x=-4,  Is -2 geometric average of -1 and -4?

For a geometric sequence you always have $a_{n}^2=a_{n-1}a_{n+1}$. Of course $a_n$ could be either positive or negative, the sign cannot be determined only by knowing $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n+1}$.


Is the geometric mean of two numbers unique?

Prove that if $a, b$ and $ c$ are three successive terms of a geometric sequence, then $b^2=ac$ $(\boldsymbol b$ is called geometric mean of $\boldsymbol a$ and $\boldsymbol c).$

I think the definition in it is vague.

Yes, the given definition is vague. The geometric mean $y$ is conventionally defined on just positive numbers $x$ and $z,$ and is always positive (and "uniquely determined", rather than merely "unique"): $$y=\sqrt{xz}.$$

For example, the geometric average of $-1$ and $-4$ can be $-2$ and $2,$ right?

No, the geometric mean of $-1$ and $-4$ is undefined, so is neither $-2$ nor $2.$

if $a$ and $c$ are negative, then then $b$ can be both positive and negative.
Is this exercise incorrect?

No, the main exercise is correct: since $$-1,-2,-4\\-1,2,-4$$ are both geometric sequences, it is indeed true that  $$(\pm2)^2=(-1)(-4),$$ even as $\{-1,-4\}$ has no geometric mean.

According to Hongwei Chen’s Means Generated by an Integral here, the geometric mean of $a$ and $b$ can be defined as $\frac{ \int_a^b x^{-1/2} \mathrm{d} x}{\int_a^b x^{-3/2}\mathrm{d} x}.$
In this way, if you plug in $a<0,b<0$, you do get $-\sqrt{ab},$ which, if we let $$\sqrt{a}:=i\sqrt{-a},$$ equals $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}.$ All this allows us to write the geometric mean of $\boldsymbol a$ and $\boldsymbol b$ as $$\sqrt{ a}\sqrt{ b}$$ whenever $a$ and $b$ have the same sign.
For example, the geometric mean of $-1$ and $-4$ is $\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{ -4}=i\sqrt{ 1}\cdot i\sqrt{ 4}=-2.$

Please revert/edit my edit if you don't like it. (In extending the definition of the geometric mean of two numbers to allow them have the same sign, I hadn't allowed either of them to be zero, as it wasn't clear that you wanted that.)

Thank you so much! This problem is in  grade 12 of our textbook. Do you think this problem is suitable for it? shouldn't  assume this definition just for positive  2 numbers here?

@FatehAkrami Please note however that if the question is (see comment by the OP): "I know that two terms of a geometric sequence are $a_{n-1}=-4$ and $a_{n+1}=-1$, what is $a_n$?", then the answer could be $a_n=-2$ or else $a_n=+2$.

@Intelligenti pauca Thank you! the original problem in textbook is:
"Prove if a and b and c are three successive of a geometric sequence, then
$b^2 = a \times{c}$ (b is called geometric mean of a and c). My question is: If the problem is true or it has a mistake? I think this definition is vague.

@FatehAkrami The problem is fine: three numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ are in geometric sequence if $a:b=b:c$, whence $b^2=ac$. What is disputable is the remark "$b$ is called geometric mean of $a$ and $c$", because that is not necessarily true.
